# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am inserting values in postgreSQL table through python script. I an getting a syntax error: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "sapiens".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pathway_parameterized.py", line 173, in <module>
    %(staging_schema, id, "homo sapiens", pathway_name, pathway_class, pathway_subclass, sub_section, ko_id, rel_path_id,rel_path_name))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "sapiens"
LINE 1: ...ath_id, related_path_name) VALUES (hsa00010, homo sapiens, G...
```

I do not understand what could be syntax error here. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the lines with enough context that raises the error and not just the error message itself.

Comment: This, "...  %(staging_schema, id, ..." tells me you are not doing proper [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and are  doing some sort of string interpolation. This is the path to SQL injection. The error occurs because  the parameters are not being properly quoted/escaped/handled. Documentation exists for a reason, take the time to go through [psycopg2 docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) and then you can solve your own problems.